# sqlalchemy - Get additional data from second table for query on first table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have three tables as such via MySQL:

```
Item
    iid     int             not null, auto_increment
    <several other columns of static data>
    primary key (iid)

Source
    sid     int             not null, auto_increment
    name    varchar(200)    not null,
    special boolean         default false,
    <other columns of static data>
    primary key (sid)

ItemSource
    isid    int             not null, auto_increment
    iid     int             not null
    sid     int             not null
    primary key (isid)
    foreign key (iid) references Item (iid)
    foreign key (sid) references Source (iid)
```

There can be zero to infinite Sources for an Item, and zero to infinite Items for a Source.  These tables are created using MySQL and then auto-loaded via

`__table_args__ = {'autoload': True}` statements in the object classes.

The SQLAlchemy call I am currently using does several filters on Item to narrow it down and is as follows:

`result = self.session.query(Item).filter(and_params).filter(or_params)`

My current code runs a by-item query on this result to get their sources, but since there can be quite a few Items returned, the code is taking a relatively long time to get everything I want.

What I am looking to do here is modify the above query somehow to also get all
Sources that are associated with the Item, and add a list of their Source.name
and Source.special to each Item I find.

**UPDATE 1:**
I have put together a mysql query and a sqlalchemy query using other posts that correctly gets exactly what I want for exactly one entry in the list:

```
SELECT Item.iid, Item.name, GROUP_CONCAT(Source.sid) as source_sids,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Source.name) as source_names,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Source.special) as source_specials
FROM ItemSource
INNER JOIN Item
ON ItemSource.iid = Item.iid
INNER JOIN Source
ON ItemSource.sid = Source.sid
WHERE Item.iid = #
```

With the sqlalchemy being:

```
result = self.session.query(
    Item,
    func.group_concat(Source.sid).label('source_sids'),
    func.group_concat(Source.name).label('source_names'),
    func.group_concat(Source.special).label('source_specials')
    ).select_from(ItemSource)\
    .join(Item, Item.iid == ItemSource.iid)\
    .join(Source, Source.sid == ItemSource.sid)\
    .filter(Item.iid == #)
```

However, if I add an or to either the mysql statement or the sqlalchemy call (such as Item.iid == 5 or Item.iid == 6), I only get one Item back and source_sids, source_names, and source_specials lumps all of the following entries that SHOULD be added as rows into the first row instead.

How can I make it so it iterates through both items (or more, if different filters are used)?

**Update 2:** Solved by adding

```
.group_by(Item.iid)
```

to the end of the SQLAlchemy query.

So, the SQLAlchemy query would be:

```
result = self.session.query(
    Item,
    func.group_concat(Source.sid).label('source_sids'),
    func.group_concat(Source.name).label('source_names'),
    func.group_concat(Source.special).label('source_specials')
    ).select_from(ItemSource)\
    .join(Item, Item.iid == ItemSource.iid)\
    .join(Source, Source.sid == ItemSource.sid)\
    .filter(Item.iid == #).group_by(Item.iid)
```

Comment: Changes made in the main post by **Update 1** and **Update 2** solve the problem.

Comment: What is `func` on `session.query`?